# How to correctly implement C# interface with event in managed C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

Hello I'm trying to implement a C# interface in my managed c++ dll as seen bellow:

```
public ref class MyClass : public IMyInterface 
{
 // Inherited via IMyInterface
 virtual event EventHandler<MyEventArgs ^> ^ MyLoadedEvent;

 public:
     virtual event EventHandler<MyEventArgs ^> MyLoadedEvent 
                {
                    void add(MyEventArgs ^ f)
                    {
                      // some magic
                    }
                    void remove(MyEventArgs ^ f)
                    {
                      // some magic
                    }
                }
}
```

But I keep getting two errors:

1) event type must be a handle-to-delegate type

2) class fails to implement interface member function "MyLoadedEvent::add" declared in ...dll

What am I missing in the implementation or what is the correct way to implement the event of the interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First error is caused by missing the ^ hat, second error is caused by not naming the interface method you implement.  Assuming the interface event is named "Loaded", correct syntax ought to resemble:

```
public ref class MyClass : IMyInterface {
    EventHandler<MyEventArgs^>^ MyLoadedEventBackingStore;
public:
    virtual event EventHandler<MyEventArgs^>^ MyLoadedEvent {
        void add(EventHandler<MyEventArgs^>^ arg) = IMyInterface::Loaded::add {
            MyLoadedEventBackingStore += arg;
        }
        void remove(EventHandler<MyEventArgs^>^ arg) = IMyInterface::Loaded::remove {
            MyLoadedEventBackingStore -= arg;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the issue for me, I got confused with all the ^ ^ in a row (no pun intended with the internet emojis)